# More Scrolling Overflowed Divs with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

My question basically goes back to this: [Scrolling Overflowed DIVS with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362/scrolling-overflowed-divs-with-javascript)

I want to know how to do that without using jQuery. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Also: in the linked question, does it scroll the div down one full scroll height each time the code is executed? If so, how can I make it scroll down with the mouse position? In other words, once I move a mouse to the bottom of the div, how can I make the div continue to scroll down, and possibly have the mouse cursor remain in the same position (this condition isn't needed but appreciated)? Thanks again in advance!

Comment: jQuery is just a JavaScript library, and open-source at that. Take a look at how jQuery does it, and copy/paste the relevant bits if you like (it's MIT licensed).

Answer (score 1):

I do believe I know precisely how to implement the effect you're looking for. I'm merely using the onmouseover and onmouseout events to start and stop a JavaScript interval mechanism which uses the scrollTop property of the div in question to emulate scrolling. Give it a whirl:

```js
<script>
var interval, cur_scroll = 0;
    
function scroll()
{
  interval = setInterval(function()
  {
    cur_scroll += 2;
    document.getElementById('testDiv').scrollTop = cur_scroll;
  }, 40);
}
     
function stop()
{
  clearInterval(interval);
}
    
document.getElementById('testDiv').setAttribute('onmouseover', 'scroll()');
document.getElementById('testDiv').setAttribute('onmouseout', 'stop()');
</script>
```

```css
<style>
#testDiv
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div id="testDiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec interdum libero sit amet diam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras eleifend tortor scelerisque mi viverra malesuada.</div>
```