# AJAX chat, auto scroll window

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

#### Duplicate

> [Scrolling Overflowed DIVs with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362/scrolling-overflowed-divs-with-javascript)

---

I have an AJAX chat that outputs the messages to a div with overflow: auto so if it gets too long, the scroll bar comes up. Is there is a way to have it auto scroll to the bottom whenever a new message is added? Preferably using jQuery?

Comment: @Brandon: this question has already been asked and answered; i've added a link to the existing discussion at the top of yours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it'd be done with the following line

```
$("#youChatDiv").attr({ scrollTop: $("#youChatDiv").attr("scrollHeight") });
```

what this does is set the scroll to the height of the own element

just call that with every new message :)

cheers

Comment: The `scrollTop` and `scrollHeight` attributes are now properties, so you should use `prop` instead of `attr`.

Answer (score 0):

Property scrollHeight is the ideal but it is not part of the W3C.

For further understanding visit:

http://yelotofu.com/2008/10/jquery-how-to-tell-if-youre-scroll-to-bottom/

Answer (score 0):

If each message is in a separate element (div, paragraph etc.), you can just call [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView)

Answer (score 0):

This Jquery plugin will help you.

[Jquery ScrollTo plugin demo page](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)