# How to increase the height of a div and warp the content in it vertically

Tags: html, css

Normally the div container height increases vertically downwards has the content in it increases. Is there a way to reverse that i.e. increase the height upwards by letting the content start at the bottom and warp upwards?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're after. Is this close to what you need? : http://jsfiddle.net/earthdesigner/vqDgV/

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by positioning your container.

**HTML**

```
<div>asdfasdfadsf safsadfsd asdfsaasdfasd asdfasd asdf</div>
```

---

**CSS**

```
div{
     position:absolute;
     bottom:15px;
}
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsbin.com/uzijed/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use Javascript for that. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741122/ajax-chat-auto-scroll-window) using JQuery.

Depending on the behaviour you're expecting, you may need to alter it. Please give more information on what you expect to happen when the user tries to scroll. Also, how/when/where is content added or removed?

Answer (score 0):

by default the div starts from the top 
and by its content increases its height downwards 
so you have to set its position with bottom then it not increases its size downwards

```
div {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:30px;


}
```

here a [fiddle](http://bit.ly/ZjSkX7) i made for you