# jQuery and Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a Rails app and need to plug in this little bit of jQuery code, but I don't really know how to get it to work. Here's my controller code:

```
class ChatroomController < ApplicationController
def send_data
    @role = Role.find_by_id(session[:role_id])
    render :juggernaut do |page|

      page.insert_html :bottom, 'chat_data', "<b>#{@role.name}:</b> #{h params[:chat_input]}<br>"
    end
    render :nothing => true
  end
end
```

and view code:

```
<h2>Chat</h2>
<html>
  <head>
    <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, :juggernaut %>
    <%= juggernaut %>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div id='chat_data', class="chatbox">
        </div>
        <br>
    <%= form_remote_tag(
          :url => { :action => :send_data },
          :complete => "$('chat_input').value = ''" ) %>
      <%= text_area_tag( 'chat_input', '', { :rows => 3, :cols => 70, :id => 'chat_input'} ) %>
      <%= submit_tag "Send" %>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, I need to make the chatroom always scroll down to the bottom when any user sends a new message. But also, when the current user has manually scrolled up, disable this sort of behaviour. I found some jQuery code here: [Scrolling Overflowed DIVs with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362/scrolling-overflowed-divs-with-javascript)

Now I don't know to get it to work. I pasted into application.js:

```
$("#chat_data").each( function() 
{
   var scrollHeight = Math.max(this.scrollHeight, this.clientHeight);
   this.scrollTop = scrollHeight - this.clientHeight;
});
```

I've also added `<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery', 'application' %>` to the `head` of my view.

But when my chatroom log fills up, the scrollbar appears but does not automatically move to the bottom as new messages come through.

Comment: exactly what code did you paste into application? 
care to leave a sample?

Comment: and what does work and what does not work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the code you've inserted is only run once, at the beginning of the script.

I don't know a lot about jquery so this is just a general solution.

```
function sub(data) {
  $('#chat_data').each( function () {
    var s_top = this.scrollHeight - this.clientHeight;
    var scl = this.scrollTop == s_top;
    this.innerHTML += '<br/>' + data;
    if ( scl ) this.scrollTop = s_top + this.clientHeight;
  })
};
```

problem is that now when you receive new data from the server you must add it into the #chat_data by calling sub("text that goes into chat window").

you'll have to replace

```
page.insert_html ....
```

with something that sends the rjs to the client, like:

```
page.call( :sub, data)
```

hope it helps.

Comment: I just put that into application.js and it doesn't work. But I suspect the auto_scroll(); bit is suppose to go somewhere else? What I don't understand is how a function is going to be called more than once when my page doesn't reload (or at least I don't think it does).

Comment: Edited my answer, see the first bit about the typo.

Comment: Still does nothing. Am I doing something wrong by just throwing the code into application.js and including it in the view?

Comment: hmmm not sure if there is anything like page.run. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/JavaScriptGenerator/GeneratorMethods.html#M001633

Comment: yea... it was page.call, sory